# Stop Composer (php) from downloading .git folder from private repo on github

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I'm using composer to install a private repo package and it keeps downloading with the .git folder.

My private repo has a release with the tag of `0.1`.

I've added a test file to my master branch to test if composer is grabbing from the master branch or from the release, and I'm able to get the release, but it still has the .git folder.

I've tried running `composer install/update` with the `--prefer-dist` flag, but it doesn't solve the problem

Here's my composer.json

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@github.com:UserName/PrivateRepo.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "UserName/PrivateRepo": "*"
  }
}
```

I've also tried (in place of the `*`):

- `dev-master` - installs the master branch
- `dev-master#0.1`- installs the master branch
- `0.1` - installs the `0.1` release
- `*` - installs the `0.1` release (note - this is my latest/only release)

But all still return with the .git folder

**Is there a way to not get the .git folder?**

And I'll add - I'm not interested into simply ignoring it in .gitignore.

Thanks

Comment: You could try using [an artifact](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#artifact) in your composer configuration to clone a bundles release - if you host with GitHub then "Releases" generate bundles automatically that you could point to

Comment: @RobbieAverill Thanks for that. It was tempting but it seems more of a hack in my case and not really a complete solution. This wouldn't be much of an issue normally, but I'm going to distribute the code and having .git folders isn't ideal.

Comment: Could you exclude the folders when you package up your code?